# Check if file exists on a Cisco switch

Tags: operating-system, filesystems, python-3.6

I am trying to check if a file exists on the internal flash:/ disk of a Cisco switch.

```
switch-2950#dir flash:/
Directory of flash:/

    2  -rwx     3721946  Jul 24 2009 16:17:10 +00:00  c2950-i6k2l2q4-mz.121-22.EA13.bin
    3  -rwx        2035  Mar 01 1993 00:25:01 +00:00  config.text
    5  drwx        4416  Jul 24 2009 16:19:50 +00:00  html
    6  -rwx         556  Mar 01 1993 00:49:35 +00:00  vlan.dat
  335  -rwx         315  Jul 24 2009 17:43:37 +00:00  env_vars
   21  -rwx         112  Jul 24 2009 16:10:20 +00:00  info
   22  -rwx         112  Jul 24 2009 16:20:56 +00:00  info.ver
   23  drwx          64  Mar 01 1993 00:00:11 +00:00  crashinfo
   25  -rwx       13495  May 18 2011 19:57:30 +00:00  config.old
  336  -rwx        3832  Mar 01 1993 00:25:01 +00:00  private-config.text

7741440 bytes total (2124800 bytes free)
```

vlan.dat clearly exists.  I can perform operations against it (such as copy).

However, I want to test if that particular file exists before performing
operations against it.

I am trying:

```
if os.path.isfile("flash:/vlan.dat"):
```

But it always returns False and the commands inside the 'if' statement are skipped over.

I have looked over numerous posts but they all cover Linux or Windows.  I can't find anything regarding a Cisco file system.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it another way.  I do a 'dir flash:/', then I check for the existence
of the 'vlan.dat' file.

```
today = time.strftime("%x")
timenow = time.strftime("%X")
filename = (hostname + '-' + '%s' + '_' + '%s') % (today, timenow)
filename = filename.replace("/", "-")
filename = filename.replace(":", "-")

ssh_channel.send("dir flash:/" + "\n")
time.sleep(0.3)
outp = ssh_channel.recv(2000)
output = outp.decode("utf-8")

if 'vlan.dat' in output:
    ssh_channel.send("copy flash:/vlan.dat tftp://192.168.1.106/" + filename + ".dat" + "\n")
    time.sleep(0.3)
```